# Ap.net Core Web API returns Result but in angular service it is undefined

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, http, asp.net-web-api, types

Asp.net core Web API returns JSON Result but in angular, I am unable to fetch that result rather it shows the undefined. Please guide me on how to check what's actually being happened wrong.
[image: Image goes here]

Angular Service Code...

```
  constructor(  private http: HttpClient ) {   }    
callExternalProject(Username : string): Observable<any>{    
       return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.CMRDashboardURL}/api/Account/LoginUserToken?username=${Username}`).pipe(
          catchError(error => {
          return throwError(() => new Error(error))
          })     
        );
      }
```

Backend Code...

```
   [HttpGet]
    [Route("LoginUserToken")]
    public IActionResult LoginUserToken(string username)
    {
        string token = "";
        MobileAPIResponseData Response = new MobileAPIResponseData();
        try
        {
            LoginDM login = new LoginDM();
            login.Username = username;


            UserDM data = new UserDM();
            data = AccountBL.CheckUserNameForLogin(login);
            if (data == null)
            {
                Response.code = 3;
                Response.message = "Invalid username password.";
                Response.Data = token;

            }
            else 
            {
                token = AccountBL.CreateToken(data.ID);
                Response.code = 200;
                Response.message = "Success";
                Response.Data = token;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommonFunctions.ErrorLog(ex, " Mobile Login API.");
            Response.code = -1;
            Response.message = "Data Exception Error";
        }

        return new JsonResult(Response);// Response;
    }
```

Comment: Can you include your code snipped where you use "callExternalProject" ?

Comment: navigateCMRD(){
 
    const username = "sc.user"
    this.erpService.callExternalProject(username)
    .pipe(first())
  .subscribe({
      next: (result) => {
        debugger
      console.log('Result is '+result);
          if (result) {      
            
            window.location.href='https://localhost:44327/Account/LoginUser?username=sc.user';

           }

}

Comment: Refer the following sample code, it works well on my side: `    http.get<any>(baseUrl + 'api/todo/LoginUserToken?username=' + username).subscribe(result => {
      var data = result;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.data);
    }, error => console.error(error));`. The output like this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDkAB.png)